# $state.go calls loads controller but not template

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a $state.go call that runs after two Factory HTTP Post calls, which redirects to a Dashboard-style page. However at no point does the associated template file load, essentially loading a white page. A refresh at this point causes the full page to load.

I am not clear on what the cause is here, as the settings in the router are consistent with what is expected as I have seen in other pages. I've attached the code below.

```
//pertinent router code
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

  .state('login', {
    url: "/login",
    templateUrl: "js/users/templates/login.html",
    controller: 'LoginController'
  })

  .state('dashboard', {
    url: '/dashboard',
    views: {
      'menuContent' :{
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'js/users/templates/dashboard.html',
        controller: 'DashboardController'
      }
    }
  })

//Segment from LoginController fired by form submit
usersService.usersFactory.authenticate(UserData).then(function successCallback(resp) {
  if (resp !== undefined) {
    $scope.go("dashboard");
  } else {
    //Not a valid login
  }
});
```

Comment: in your route's keep `cache:false` as a property than your problem will be solved. Ex: `.state('login', {
    url: "/login",
    cache:false,
    templateUrl: "js/users/templates/login.html",
    controller: 'LoginController'
  })`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell there are two issues with your snippet

**State definition**

```
views: {
    'menuContent' :{
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'js/users/templates/dashboard.html',
        controller: 'DashboardController'
    }
}
```

You are setting the property `abstract: true` in your view, that's the wrong place to set it, it should be part of the state definition. Further more if you set your state as abstract will raise an exception since abstract states cannot be navigated directly. My suggestion would be to remove that property from your state as you clearly don't need it.

You can read more about the abstract behavior at [ui-router docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider)

> An abstract state will never be directly activated, but can provide
>   inherited properties to its common children states.

**State redirect**

```
usersService.usersFactory.authenticate(UserData).then(function successCallback(resp) {
      if (resp !== undefined) {
        $scope.go("dashboard");
      } else {
        //Not a valid login
      }
    });
```

You are referencing `$scope.go` when it should be `$state.go`.

Answer (score 0):

Its `$state.go` not `$scope.go`
Please use the following code in your controller.

```
usersService.usersFactory.authenticate(UserData).then(function successCallback(resp) {
  if (resp !== undefined) {
    $state.go("dashboard");
  } else {
    //Not a valid login
  }
});
```